# Modifier will get executed in the EVM or no?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, evm, pending-transactions, txpool

where  Modifier executed?

in block 1, for example i want send 10 eth to a contract address. in the modifier i will check that contract address should have 0 eth balance. The check is done at the modifier and allows the transaction to be created and sent to the network. now due to network congestion, my transaction will stay pending for 5 blocks. but in block 2, The contract will receive 0.1 eth and the contract balance is no longer zero. now, in block number 5, my transaction will be done and 10 eth will be sent to the contract, or my transaction will get revert ?

Answer (score 0):

The modifier is executed when the function is called.

In block 1: modifier executed sees that transaction has 0 eth
function gets executed: 10 eth is sent to contract address

block 2: contract address receives 0.1 eth

block 5: modifer is executed again but fails
transaction is reverted. Eth is not sent to the contract address